# How should I create a listbox in a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to have a listbox where users can add items they have entered in a text input. The list should also have remove, edit functionality.

What's the best way to do this (i.e. hardcode or is there a jquery)? I am guessing would need javascript which is fine.

How would I read all the values from JS? I want to concatenate the items with a delimiter so that I can send it via ajax

Comment: You can send whole objects in AJAX encoded as JSON.  No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Brad Which part is reinventing the wheel? Right now the server code is configured to take in | delimited string so... if I send an object I have to reconfigure the server side... I would rather just send the listbox as a delimited string

Comment: If you already have server-side code written to parse that, then fine.  I'm suggesting that there is no need to invent new formats to represent data in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using jQuery adding all options from a listbox to a comma delimited string;

```javascript
function toAllan() {
  var allanString = "";
  var allanOptions = $('.myListBox option');
  allanOptions.each(function (index) {
    allanString += $(this).val();
    if (index != allanOptions.length - 1) {
      allanString += ",";
    }
  });
  return allanString;
}
```

**EDIT** I ran across this alternative which is much cleaner IMO.

```javascript
function toAllan() {
  return $('#myListBox option').map(function (index) {
      return $(this).val();
  }).get().join(',');
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle demonstrating this (also includes adding and removing of elements from the list box): http://jsfiddle.net/srGz7/4/

Comment: Do you know how to add the entered text from a textbox into the listbox? And also remove a selected item from the list?

Comment: I've updated my jsFiddle example to include this functionality. Have a look. Lemme know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, will modify it a bit but looks like it can do everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can take a look at this jquery plugin - [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/). However you can't edit the item.

Comment: This looks very good, there's just one small problem. The user should be able to enter in items not in the returned results. I don't see a configuration setting for that

Comment: Yes, you can enter new items. I made a new demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anthony_yuan/7QCCb/). You can have a try. Just enter a new item and type the token delimiter (customizable) ','. Note: an undocumented option is used here: allowFreeTagging.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I've already done it the simple way, I will probably change it over at a later time tho once everything else is done

Comment: hm... its a bit buggy, for example if I type "test" (no quotes), it will show a result for "Testee". If I'm really fast and press , it will enter Test but after that it wont recognize any other ,s.